# SVG containing <symbol> inside of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, svg

I am trying to import a SVG file that I exported from [Ipe](http://ipe.otfried.org/). The exported files all work fine except for the files to which I added text to in Ipe.

The warning I get from Android Studio says `The image may be incomplete due to encountered issues` and when I check the issues, it's just lines of `ERROR @ line X: <symbol> is not supported`. It seems that Android Studio does not support `<symbol>` inside of SVG files.

My question is, is there an utility that would allow me to convert this SVG file to an SVG file or directly to the XML file that Android Studio would support? If not, how would I go about doing this kind of thing manually? Ipe also supports exporting as EPS, but when trying to convert that back to SVG, the convertor that I used still used `<symbol>`.

To show how the SVG file looks and not to spam this whole question with hundreds of lines, I created a simple text box containing `1` and exported it as a SVG file to have an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="7pt" height="9pt" viewBox="0 0 7 9" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <g>
      <symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-0">
        <path style="stroke:none;" d=""/>
      </symbol>
      <symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-1">
        <path style="stroke:none;" d="M 2.9375 -6.375 C 2.9375 -6.625 2.9375 -6.640625 2.703125 -6.640625 C 2.078125 -6 1.203125 -6 0.890625 -6 L 0.890625 -5.6875 C 1.09375 -5.6875 1.671875 -5.6875 2.1875 -5.953125 L 2.1875 -0.78125 C 2.1875 -0.421875 2.15625 -0.3125 1.265625 -0.3125 L 0.953125 -0.3125 L 0.953125 0 C 1.296875 -0.03125 2.15625 -0.03125 2.5625 -0.03125 C 2.953125 -0.03125 3.828125 -0.03125 4.171875 0 L 4.171875 -0.3125 L 3.859375 -0.3125 C 2.953125 -0.3125 2.9375 -0.421875 2.9375 -0.78125 Z M 2.9375 -6.375 "/>
      </symbol>
    </g>
  </defs>
  <g id="surface1894">
    <g style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">
      <use xlink:href="#glyph0-1" x="1" y="8"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: if symbol is not supported, in this case, you can use a group instead since you don't have a width and height for the use element. You can also try using nested svg instead of the symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to replace `<symbol>` with a group `<g>`, while also moving `overflow="visible"` inside of the `<path>` that belongs to the group.

```
  <g id="glyph0-1">
    <path overflow="visible" style="stroke:none;" d="M 2.9375 -6.375 C 2.9375 -6.625 2.9375 -6.640625 2.703125 -6.640625 C 2.078125 -6 1.203125 -6 0.890625 -6 L 0.890625 -5.6875 C 1.09375 -5.6875 1.671875 -5.6875 2.1875 -5.953125 L 2.1875 -0.78125 C 2.1875 -0.421875 2.15625 -0.3125 1.265625 -0.3125 L 0.953125 -0.3125 L 0.953125 0 C 1.296875 -0.03125 2.15625 -0.03125 2.5625 -0.03125 C 2.953125 -0.03125 3.828125 -0.03125 4.171875 0 L 4.171875 -0.3125 L 3.859375 -0.3125 C 2.953125 -0.3125 2.9375 -0.421875 2.9375 -0.78125 Z M 2.9375 -6.375 "/>
  </g>
```

After doing that, Android Studio will show the letters. The only issue left is that all the letters are black instead of being colored.

To fix this issue, its just a matter of moving the `style` arguments to the path in the group that's being referenced. In this case that's the path inside the group `glyph0-1`, which results in this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="7pt" height="9pt" viewBox="0 0 7 9" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <g>
      <g id="glyph0-0">
        <path overflow="visible" style="stroke:none;" d=""/>
      </g>
      <g id="glyph0-1">
        <!-- just added the arguments to the beginning of the string. -->
        <path overflow="visible" style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;" d="M 2.9375 -6.375 C 2.9375 -6.625 2.9375 -6.640625 2.703125 -6.640625 C 2.078125 -6 1.203125 -6 0.890625 -6 L 0.890625 -5.6875 C 1.09375 -5.6875 1.671875 -5.6875 2.1875 -5.953125 L 2.1875 -0.78125 C 2.1875 -0.421875 2.15625 -0.3125 1.265625 -0.3125 L 0.953125 -0.3125 L 0.953125 0 C 1.296875 -0.03125 2.15625 -0.03125 2.5625 -0.03125 C 2.953125 -0.03125 3.828125 -0.03125 4.171875 0 L 4.171875 -0.3125 L 3.859375 -0.3125 C 2.953125 -0.3125 2.9375 -0.421875 2.9375 -0.78125 Z M 2.9375 -6.375 "/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </defs>
  <g id="surface1894">
    <!-- Removed the group that <use> was in, because there is no need for an empty group. -->
    <use xlink:href="#glyph0-1" x="1" y="8"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

There's only one more optional step left and that is to delete the unused groups. It seems that Ipe adds a `<symbol>` that's called `glyphN-0`, N being a different number for each "text object" exported from Ipe. This `<symbol>` seems to have no use because the only `<symbol>` that's being used is the one named `glyphN-1`. Deleting this `<symbol>` doesn't do anything, so I would suggest everyone to delete it to clear the file a little bit. This results in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="7pt" height="9pt" viewBox="0 0 7 9" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <g>
      <g id="glyph0-1">
        <path overflow="visible" style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;" d="M 2.9375 -6.375 C 2.9375 -6.625 2.9375 -6.640625 2.703125 -6.640625 C 2.078125 -6 1.203125 -6 0.890625 -6 L 0.890625 -5.6875 C 1.09375 -5.6875 1.671875 -5.6875 2.1875 -5.953125 L 2.1875 -0.78125 C 2.1875 -0.421875 2.15625 -0.3125 1.265625 -0.3125 L 0.953125 -0.3125 L 0.953125 0 C 1.296875 -0.03125 2.15625 -0.03125 2.5625 -0.03125 C 2.953125 -0.03125 3.828125 -0.03125 4.171875 0 L 4.171875 -0.3125 L 3.859375 -0.3125 C 2.953125 -0.3125 2.9375 -0.421875 2.9375 -0.78125 Z M 2.9375 -6.375 "/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </defs>
  <g id="surface1894">
    <use xlink:href="#glyph0-1" x="1" y="8"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Thanks to enxaneta for leading me to the right answer in the comments.